# React Native lazy loading 250 images in a Scroll View

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have 250 objects in state, that I'm trying to load in a scroll view with an image for each one. I'm using react-native-lazyload, and it works for about the first 75 images, then the scrolling starts slowing down to a halt, almost at the same spot every time.

Is there a different way I can load these images? It seems like a Flatlist would be a better option than a Scrollview, but I have no function I can call onEndReach

Comment: Where are the images stored on the device or on the internet?

Comment: I prefer [recycler list view](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview). Although, it is not as easy to use as FlatList, but does the job pretty well

Comment: @Andrew on the internet

Comment: Have you considered using `react-native-fast-image`?

Comment: @Andrew I tried using it but ran into 'Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "FastImageView" was not found in the UIManager.' I'm using crna 2.0.2. I'm not sure if I can use this without ejecting.

Comment: You won't be able to use that with Expo.

Comment: @Andrew hmm, shoot. Are there any other options?

Comment: That’s the most performant image caching system that I’ve seen. I don’t think there is anything like that for expo

Comment: @Andrew I found a solution to improve the performance of Flatlists. I posted it if you are interested.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found a really good write-up on improving performance of Flatlists [here](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips). I ended up using a Flatlist with these setting:

```
  <FlatList
    containerContentStyle={styles.container}
    data={countries}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View style={styles.results}>
        <Results 
          {...this.props} 
          country={item} 
          handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
          pendingCountry={pendingCountry}
        />
      </View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item.alpha2code}
    ListHeaderComponent={() => this.renderHeader()}

    // Performance settings
    removeClippedSubviews={true} // Unmount components when outside of window 
    initialNumToRender={2} // Reduce initial render amount
    maxToRenderPerBatch={1} // Reduce number in each render batch
    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100} // Increase time between renders
    windowSize={7} // Reduce the window size
  />
```

I can now scroll through my entire list of 250 images at a reasonable pace with no issues. When I start scrolling back up from the bottom, the screen gets a little jerky, but this is the best solution I've gotten to work.

Comment: I think the second 'maxToRenderPerBatch' should be 'updateCellsBatchingPeriod'. Otherwise great answer though. Thanks!