# How lazy load images in react native within flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native, lazy-loading, react-native-flatlist, react-lazy-load

I'm looking there is a solution to lazy load images in react in react native. I have a flatlist which contains card component with an image. I'm looking to implement lazy load image in react native.
Please take into account that the uri is dynamic and I'm using FastImage to display the image.

I've found react-lazyload and react-native-lazy-load.
But I don't know if I can use them, the first I think is for react and the second is archived and didn't have any updates since 2021.

Comment: is this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032060/react-native-lazy-loading-250-images-in-a-scroll-view?rq=2